# Delphi Login Form using App Tethering by Connecting to SQLite Database

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

***Hi, EveryBody!***

***I'm new to programming!***

***I need your help plz.***

*I've 2 project:*

*1. Project Login page. **Using App Tethering** and 2 buttons(Connect button =>connects to the server AND Login button=>Sends request to the Server to check Valid username and password).*

*2. Project Server page. In a Server Page using App tethering and FDQuery +(**SQLite** database test.db).
When Client Connects to the Server and sends request to the Server to check valid username and password it gives wrong result. **plz help me to make work correctly.***

[image: Client And Server]

**1 Project Code:**

```
procedure TfAuth.bLogin(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles.First,'Login',tLogin.Text);
  tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles.First,'Password',tPassword.Text);
end;
```

**2. Project Code:**
**I creat global var**

```
 private

    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var

  aLogin, aPassword:string;

implementation


{$R *.fmx}
```

***Then I put put this code on TetherAppProfile=>OnResourceReceived*** :

```
procedure TfServerPage.tAProfileResourceReceived(const Sender: TObject;
  const AResource: TRemoteResource);
  begin

   if AResource.Hint='Login' then
      begin
      aLogin:=AResource.Value.AsString;
      end;

   if AResource.Hint='Password' then
      begin
      aPassword:=AResource.Value.AsString;
      end;
 rQuery.Close;
      rQuery.SQL.Clear;
      rQuery.SQL.Add('select * from authoriation where name='+QuotedStr(aLogin)+'and password='+QuotedStr(aPassword));
      rQuery.Open;
      if rQuery.RecordCount=0 then   // No record found for user
        ShowMessage('Be sure user name and password is correct')
      else
        begin
          ShowMessage('Success!');
        end;
```

Comment: Do both Login and Password reach the tAProfileResourceReceived at the same time, or does the client two executions of tAProfileResourceReceived (one per tAProfile.SendString)?

Comment: On the Client Side I 've two request(username,password) to Server. On the server only one Receiver  tAProfileResourceReceived.

Comment: What values does the server actually receive?

Comment: AResource.Value.AsString;

Comment: I think you need to send both login and password simultaneously, so you have both available when you query the db. You can send them both in a similar way as in my previous answer, in a `TStringList` or just concatenate before sending with a special character, which you can use to split the string in two at reception.

Comment: I tried too many times with [TStrings,TStringList], not working...! :(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

In client

```
procedure TfAuth.bLogin(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := tLogin.Text + #13 + tPassword.Text;
  tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles.First,'Login',s);
//  tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles.First,'Login',tLogin.Text);
//  tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles.First,'Password',tPassword.Text);
end;
```

Note!This uses the server resource named 'Login'.

In server

```
procedure TfServerPage.tAProfileResourceReceived(const Sender: TObject;
  const AResource: TRemoteResource);
var
  s: string;
begin
// replace current code before rQuery.Close with the following
  s := AResource.Value.AsString;

  aLogin := copy(s, 1, Pos(#13, s)-1);
  aPassword := copy(s, Pos(#13, s)+1, Length(s));

  rQuery.Close;
// continue with rQuery
// ...
end;
```

---

Alternative in the server using `SplitString()`

```
uses System.Types, System.StrUtils ...;

procedure TFrmLoginServer.ServTetProfResourceReceived(const Sender: TObject;
  const AResource: TRemoteResource);
var
  ss: TStringDynArray;
begin
  ss := SplitString(AResource.Value.AsString, #13);
  aLogin := ss[0];
  aPassword := ss[1];
end;
```

Comment: Bro, I don't unserstand 1, -1,+1,Length(s).  Is there any other option to make understandable??? plz

Comment: Thanks bro! I got ;)))

Comment: What if   

s:=tLogin.Text+#13+tPassword.Text+#13+Edit1.Text+#13+Edit2.Text;

aLogin := copy(s, 1, Pos(#13, s)-1);
aPassword := copy(s, Pos(#13, s)+1);
aV:=???????
aB:=???????

Comment: Bro, I'm using like...: 

s:=tLogin.Text+#13+tPassword.Text+#13+Edit1.Text; 
  aLogin:=SplitString(s,#13)[0];
  aPassword:=SplitString(s,#13)[1];
  z:=SplitString(s,#13)[2];
  
and it works. Thank you very much Tom. You are my Hero ;)))

Comment: @Alex Instead of calling `SplitString()` several times, call it only ones and assign its result to a local variable of type `TStringDynArray`. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: I'll Bro ! ;)))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056070/how-to-split-string-by-splitstring-or-delimiter