# How to Split string by SplitString or delimiter?

Tags: delphi

I've Client And Server Apps.
I'm using App tethering in both side.
In a Server Side I've SQLite database
In a Client Side There is no database;
Client getting data from Server database.
With Server Code I think it Is ok. Problem with Client ,I can not  Splite!!! I wrote code on Client Side . Can someone tell me , where is my mistake???
How to Split r3.Text:=AResource.Value.AsString; ?

**Server Side Code:**

```
procedure TfServerPage.tAProfileResourceReceived(const Sender: TObject;
  const AResource: TRemoteResource);
  var
    result:string;
    r1,r2,r3:TstringList;
  begin

if AResource.Hint='List' then
        begin
          //ShowMessage(AResource.Value.AsString);
            r1:=TStringList.Create;
            r2:=TStringList.Create;
            r3:=TStringList.Create;
            rQuery.Open;
             while not rQuery.Eof do
                begin
                 r1.add(rQuery.FieldByName('username').AsString);
                 r2.add(rQuery.FieldByName('password').AsString);
                 r3.add(rQuery.FieldByName('nickname').AsString);
                 rQuery.Next;
                end;
            result:=r1.Text+#13+r2.Text+#13+r3.text;
           tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles.First,'List2',result);

        end;
end;
```

**Client Side Code:**

```
procedure TfAuth.tAProfileResourceReceived(const Sender: TObject;
  const AResource: TRemoteResource);
var i:integer;
r3,s1,s2,s3:TStringList;
begin


    if AResource.Hint='List2' then
      begin
        r3:=TStringList.Create;
        r3.Text:=AResource.Value.AsString;    // <-From Server

        s1:=TStringList.Create;
        s2:=TStringList.Create;
        s3:=TStringList.Create;

      s1.Text:=SplitString(r3.Text,#13)[0]; //Split username
      s2.Text:=SplitString(r3.Text,#13)[1]; //password
      s3.Text:=SplitString(r3.Text,#13)[2]; //nickname

       for i := 0 to r3.Count do
           begin
            StringGrid1.Cells[0,i]:=s1[i];   
            StringGrid1.Cells[1,i]:=s2[i];  
            StringGrid1.Cells[2,i]:=s3[i]; 
           end;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: I think you should write `s1.Add (SplitString(r3.Text,#13)[0] );` Instead of `s1.Text:=SplitString(r3.Text,#13)[0]`;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Side Code:**

```
 result:=r1.Text+#0+r2.Text+#0+r3.text;
```

**Client Side Code:**

```
 s1.Text:=SplitString(r3.Text,#0)[0];

  s2.Text:=SplitString(r3.Text,#0)[1];

  s3.Text:=SplitString(r3.Text,#0)[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you add fields from db records to 3 string lists, r1 - usernames, r2 - passwords and r3 - nicknames. String lists use CarriageReturn - LineFeed ( or #13#10) as end-of-line characters as default.

When you concatenate the texts of these string lists with a #13 between the r1.Text, r2.Text and r3.Text, the splitting back into string lists based on #13 goes wrong. You should use some other character as separator for the string lists. Try with e.g. #11 (vertical tab).

I would also use just a `s:string` instead of the `r3:TStringList` on the client side.

You are leaking memory and should free the `TStringList`'s!

Better though, if you are going to transfer larger data records, you should consider to use XML or JSON. Those provide means to serialize data in a more convenient way.

Comment: Bro, How to Use  JSON in My case...? ;((((

Comment: Sorry Alex, but that is a too broad topic to be answered here on Stack Overflow. For a starter look in the Help and samples, Google for "delphi json" etc. There are plenty of docs and articles on the net.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140246/delphi-how-to-get-all-images-from-server-database-by-using-app-tethering