# Delphi: How to make TButtons 3x3?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I've created multi TButtons.
[image: Created Buttons]

Problem is I'd like created buttons looks like 3x3. 
[image: 3x3]

How to do that?
Note: Buttons will be more!

My code:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateButtonsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
B: TButton;
begin
for i:= 1 to 7 do
  begin
    B := TButton.Create(Self);
    B.Text := Format('Button %d', [i]);
    B.Parent := Self;
    B.Height := 23;
    B.Width := 100;
    B.Position.X:=25 + i* 105;
    B.Position.Y:=70;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Simply use a TGridLayout component and add in it the buttons

Comment: Delphi 7 and FireMonkey??? Could you please fix those tags? As for the answer, I agree with Alberto, you should use layouts. I'd go with the TGridPanelLayout. And use <Layout>.AddObject(<Button>), instead of <Button>. Parent := <Layout>.

Comment: use `mod` and `div` operators  to get position in row and in column

Comment: @AlbertoMiola I'm trying to use TGridLayout. Could you help me to add in my code,  please!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is: Tool Palette->search->GridLayout

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are right, I'm using Delphi XE8 Multi-Device Application.

Comment: Good. I fixed your tags. You added XE7 for some reason. You are using XE8. And I added back firemonkey which is important.

Comment: In future, please do not waste readers' time saying you are trying to use a TGridLayout and then accept an answer that does not use one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned using a TGridLayout, here is some code which show how to modify your code to lay out some TButtons in one, in a manner resembling your screenshot:

```
procedure TForm1.AButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(TButton(Sender).Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateButtons;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateButtons;
var
  i:integer;
  B: TButton;
begin
  GridLayout1.ItemWidth := 100;
  GridLayout1.ItemHeight := 23;
  for i:= 1 to 7 do
    begin
      B := TButton.Create(Self);
      GridLayout1.AddObject(B);
      B.Text := Format('Button %d', [i]);
      B.Margins.Left := 5;
      B.Margins.Top := 5;
      B.OnClick := AButtonClick;
      //B.Parent := Self;
      //B.Height := 23;
      //B.Width := 100;
      //B.Position.X:=25 + i* 105;
      //B.Position.Y:=70;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: When I click button  pop-ups :ACCESS VIOLATION message

Comment: Then you have a mistake somewhere.  Paste my updated code into a new project - it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Then debug it and find out where the alleged AV occurs.  "not working" is not a helpful description.  Do you know how to trace an AV?

Comment: I Got this message: Project Client.exe araised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x008519ce: read of address 0x41500000'

Comment: That tells other readers virtually nothing.  You didn't answer my question: Do you know how to trace an AV?

Comment: Project Client.exe araised exception class EArgumentOutRangeException with message 'Argument out  of range'.

Comment: No I don't know trace an AV.

Comment: Well, its pointless trying to do any serious Delphi development until you do, otherwise you'll just be posting "Doesn't work2 for the rest of your career..  First, in your project's Compiler Options, under Compiling, check the boxes `Use debug DCUs` and `Stack frames`.  Under Tools | Options check the box `Notify on languages exception`. Then do a build (not compile) of your project and let it run until the AV occurs [cont]

Comment: Once you've got the AV, go to View | Debug Windows | Call stack.  At the top of the pop-up is where the AV occurred, which may be somewhere for which the source is available, maybe not.  If not, look down the pop-up until you find a line which has source code.  Then, you can start figuring out why the AV occurred.

Comment: @Alex I just tried Martyn's solution and it works correctly. You must have done something wrong, but it is not possible to help you if the only thing you can say is "it doesn't work". Please try harder.

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Thanks for taking the trouble to confirm, Tom, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MartynA I restart my Delphi XE8 and run it works now big thanks . By the way I've 1 quation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904692/how-to-use-app-tethering-with-internet-connection

Comment: @AlexKirov:  Glad you got it working.  Anyway: now you know.  The very first thing to do when you run into an unexpected AV when running simple, tested code, is to restart Delphi.  If the AV persists, especially with db applications, restart your PC, because the ADO layer can get into corrupt states that don't get cleared until windows restarts.

Comment: @MartynA I'll! :)))) can you have a look please for a long time I can't not find solution for this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904692/how-to-use-app-tethering-with-internet-connection

Comment: @AlexKirov:  I see that Remy Lebeau has answered your q about tethering over the internet.  I am afraid I know far less about the subject than he does.

Comment: @MartynA 
Yes, it's possible to connect App Tethering via internet. Can you help me step by step to solve this problem. docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Connecting_to_Remote_Applications_Using_App_Tethering

Comment: @AlexKirov:  Sorry, this would be sure to involve Indy and I avoid that library like the plague

Comment: @MartynA I need your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992103/idtcpclient-and-idtcpserver-exchanging-data-on-desktops-and-not-android

Comment: @AlexKirov:  Sorry, as I said, I don't do Indy stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I tested the code with Lazarus (sorry, I haven't Delphi right now) but it should work with your version. If not - replace **Top** and **Left** with **Position**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  B: TButton;
begin
  for i := 0 to 13 do
  begin
    B := TButton.Create(Self);
    B.Caption := Format('Button %d', [i + 1]);
    B.Parent := Self;
    B.Height := 23;
    B.Width := 100;
    B.Left := 25 + (i mod 3) * 105;
    B.Top := 70 + (i div 3) * 70;
  end;

end;
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously real world code would need to respect font scaling

Comment: Sure, completely agree with you. But it's just an example how to use math to place elements. Usually I'm using something like grid-system to display elements