# How to use App Tethering with internet connection?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio Delphi XE8.

Multi-Device Application app tethering components are designed for traditional WiFi and Bluetooth coupling. Does it support also Internet connections?

I would like to try to make small p2p app. I'm using App tethering via Wifi but I would like to connect App tethering via internet connection.

how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TCP/IP (LAN and Internet) is also supported.  This is clearly explained in the documentation.

[Using App Tethering](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_App_Tethering)

> The app tethering feature does not depend on a specific transport or protocol, and new transports and protocols can be implemented using the app tethering API. **The RTL provides built-in support for IP and Classic Bluetooth connections**. IP support includes connecting applications running on the same device.

IP connections are not limited to WiFi only.  WiFi is just a wireless connection to a LAN, much like Ethernet is for wired connections.  IP works the same regardless of the type of connection used.

[Connecting to Remote Applications Using App Tethering | Connecting to Applications Outside Your Subnet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connecting_to_Remote_Applications_Using_App_Tethering#Connecting_to_Applications_Outside_Your_Subnet)

> By default, both `AutoConnect` and `DiscoverManagers` perform the discovery on the subnet of the local area network (LAN) where the device running your application is.
>
> However, you can use their optional parameter `Target` to override this behavior, and specify an IP address or subnet:
>
> - To specify an IP address to search for remote managers, specify that IP address as the `Target`.
> - To specify a subnet of IP addresses, specify an IP address with a 0 as its fourth number. For example, if you specify "192.168.4.0" as the Target, your manager searches the 192.168.4.x subnet for remote managers. Note: You can not specify wider subnets. For example, "192.168.0.0" is not supported.