# How UPDATE Client database From Server Database?

Tags: delphi

**Hi, Guys!**

I'm new to Programming. I need your help!

**I'm using Delphi-xe8. App ->Multi-Device Application**

I've 2 Apps Let's call Server And Client.

[image: ClientandServer]

[image: ClientDBandServerDB]

I need when Client click 'CONNECT' , Client Database Should Update from Server Database!

**Note:** I'm using in a both side SQLite.

I need the easiest way.

Q? How UPDATE Client database From Server Database Using App tethering?

Comment: @Tom, I know Sorry. I am still not get correct answer. I think some guys don't get my question. So I make My question clear now, let's see!!!

Comment: With respect, the reason you have not got a correct answer yet (and I've spent a long time on it) is that until now you've shown us virtually nothing of your server and client, so it's rather difficult to identify exactly what your problem is. What software are your screenshots Client DB and Server DB actually showing? Presumably the software is not your client, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Dear @ MartynA 9 actually I like your answer for my ?. Regarding software Client/Server DB I'm using 'SQLite Expert Personal' with the help of this I'm creating ...*.db and u can add,delete...

Comment: Ok, so which of your questions do you think is still not answered, and why, exactly?  What is it that you still do not know how to do?

Comment: Why on earth would you put a FideDAC FDConnection and a TClientDataSet in your client?  Why not use a FireDAC dataset like an FDMemTable instead?

Comment: @ MartynA: On Client Side I put FDConnection,DSProviderConnection1 and ClientDataSet1. but on Properties DSProviderConnection1->ServerClassName:....? what I need ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135498/discussion-between-alex-kirov-and-martyna).

Comment: Sorry, I think you (or your qs) are in a complete muddle and need to slow down.  I have absolutely no idea why you would have "FDConnection,DSProviderConnection1 and ClientDataSet1" in your client it you are trying to transfer the data using app tethering.

Comment: @ MartynA :Ok, Let's Start from begining Which Exact Components Do I need on Client Side?

Comment: I have explained in the chat session you invited me to.

Comment: @ MartynA  In a StringGrid I changed from category ex: Cod into Cod2 it's changing in a both side. but when I close and open again it's showing old name like Cod.

Comment: @ MartynA Sorry I wanted message on a Chat session but its giving me: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. that's why I'm typing here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer to your earlier q here: [How to Get Images From Server using App Tethering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153215/how-to-get-images-from-server-using-app-tethering/42154115#42154115) showed you how to transfer data in a TClientDataSet in the server to one in a client using app tethering.

That method of transfer relies on a TClientDataSet's ability to save its data to a stream on the server side and to load it from a stream on the client side, using its `SaveToStream` and `LoadFromStream`.  In this q, although you haven't said what your 2 rQuery components are, you are obviously using FireDAC, and its FDQuery, FDMemTable, etc have `SaveToStream` and `LoadFromStream` methods which work in a similar, virtually identical manner (from the user's pov) to the TClientDataSet.  So to "update" your client-side dataset from the server-side one, you can use your dataset components in a similar manner as I've shown in my answer to your other q.

To save other readers a visit to the other q, the FireDAC code is

Server:

```
procedure TServerApp.DataSetToStream;
var
  Stream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  FDQuery1.SaveToStream(Stream);
  Stream.Position := 0;
  TetheringAppProfile1.Resources.FindByName('BioLife').Value := Stream;
end;
```

Client

```
procedure TCliemtApp.TetheringAppProfile1Resources0ResourceReceived(const Sender:
    TObject; const AResource: TRemoteResource);
begin
  AResource.Value.AsStream.Position := 0;
  FDMemTable1.LoadFromStream(AResource.Value.AsStream);
end;
```